# Trigonometry : The smallest positive value of $x$ ( in degrees ) for which $\tan ( x + 100°) = \tan ( x + 50° ) \tan x \tan ( x - 50°)$ is

Tags: trigonometry

Find the smallest positive value of $x$ ( in degrees ) for which $$\tan ( x + 100°) = \tan ( x + 50° ) \tan x \tan ( x - 50°)$$ My answer is too long and I don't think that this question deserves so long answer I will post my answer as soon as I got time, but need your help for a short answer. [image]

Sorry , guys for bad handwriting but I think that you will be able to know my way of this solution

Comment: You better post your solution now or this will be closed and you will get no answer.

Comment: It seems like the Fermat trick for his last theorem!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/621213/determine-the-smallest-positive-value-of-xin-degrees-for-which-tanx100

Comment: Thanks lab bhattacharjee

Comment: The fact that you do not mention the value $30^\circ$ of the solution gives a lot of credit points against trusting you have an answer, even after a long computation. Please always show the own effort, at least tell us the idea. (If no idea of computation or of insight can be extracted, than please give something that can be trusted.)

Answer (score 1):

We substitue $\alpha=\frac{50}{100}\pi$ then we get the equation

$$\tan(x+2\alpha)=\tan(x+\alpha)\tan(x)\tan(x-\alpha)$$,
this equation can be simplified to

$$\left( \tan \left( x \right)  \right) ^{3} \left( \tan \left( \alpha
 \right)  \right) ^{4}+2\, \left( \tan \left( x \right)  \right) ^{4}
\tan \left( \alpha \right) -4\, \left( \tan \left( x \right)  \right) 
^{2} \left( \tan \left( \alpha \right)  \right) ^{3}-\tan \left( x
 \right)  \left( \tan \left( \alpha \right)  \right) ^{4}- \left( \tan
 \left( x \right)  \right) ^{3}+\tan \left( x \right) +2\,\tan \left( 
\alpha \right) 
=0$$
Now Substitute $$\tan(x)=t$$ and you will get an equation of degree four in $t$.