# Determine the smallest positive solution $x$ to equation $\tan(x+100^\circ)=\tan(x+50^\circ)\tan x\tan(x-50^\circ)$

Tags: trigonometry

Determine the smallest positive value of $x$, in degrees, for which

$$\tan(x+100^\circ)=\tan(x+50^\circ)\tan x\tan(x-50^\circ)\tag{1}$$

I tried to solve it in various ways but didn't get any breakthroughs.

Please help me in this.

Comment: Would you mind adding some additional information about what you have tried so far and where did you get stuck?

Comment: actually I put what I tried, but didn't get any response. So I tried submitting without that.

Comment: Well, now you can put all of that back and it will bump your question again.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/621213/determine-the-smallest-positive-value-of-xin-degrees-for-which-tanx100

Answer (score 3):

Rewrite the equation,

$$\tan(x+100^\circ)=\tan(x+50^\circ)\tan x\tan(x-50^\circ)$$

as,

$$\frac{\sin (x + 100) \cos(x-50) }{\cos(x + 100) \sin(x-50) } = \frac{\sin(x+50)\sin x}{\cos(x+50)\cos x}$$

Apply the trigonometric product identities to get
$$\frac{\sin (2x + 50) + \frac12}{\sin (2x+50) - \frac12} = \frac{\cos  50 - \cos(2x+50)}{\cos 50 + \cos (2x+50)}$$

where $\sin 150 =\frac12$ is used. Multiply out and then simplify to obtain,

$$\sin(4x + 100)  = -\sin 40$$

which yields the smallest positive solution $x=30^\circ$.

Answer (score 1):

I will solve for $x$ then pick the smallest 
$$\tan a \tan b = \frac{\sin a \sin b }{\cos a \cos b } = \frac{\cos(a-b)-\cos(a+b)}{\cos(a-b)+\cos (a-b) } $$
$$\tan a \cot b = \frac{\sin a \cos b}{\cos a \sin b}=\frac{\sin(a+b)+\sin(a-b)}{\sin(a+b) - \sin(a-b)}$$
Hence 
I will try to get similar angles in both sides so I will move like this

$$\tan ( 100+x) \cot (x-50) = \tan (x) \tan (x+50) $$
$$\frac{\sin (2x + 50) + \sin 50}{\sin (2x+50) - \sin 50} = \frac{\cos ( 50) - \cos(2x+50)}{\cos (50) + \cos (2x+50)}$$
can you proceed?? ( try cross multiple )